# Visual Studio Code doesn't downloading

Tags: visual-studio-code, download, load

Visual Studio Code doesn't downloading from its official website. What's the problem?

I tried with different devices with different browsers for different times. I restarted devices but still not downloading. It is not internet connection, antivirus, cache or etc. Don't know what it is, but not this easy. Can you download now?

Comment: Restart your device.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading from [here.](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) Select the desired Operating System

Comment: I tried  before this too, again did it after you said. I tried with different devices with different browsers for different times. I restarted devices but still not downloading.